# Usando aplicación del tiempo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Buenas estoy intentando crear una aplicación del tiempo que funcione mediante Ajax, esta aplicación usa weathermap, de donde pilla la información y la muestra.

Os pongo lo que tengo actualmente, que no me sirve y no sé por qué, no me carga la información.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>El tiempo - </title>
    <!--Inclusión de libreria jquery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        label {
            width: 150px;
            float: left;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        input,
        select {
            width: 150px;
            float: left;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        fieldset {
            width: 350px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Aplicación para consultar el Tiempo:</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>El Tiempo</legend>
        <form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="" method="get">
            <label for="lugar">Ubicación </label>
            <!--Solicito el nombre de la Ubicación para mostrar el tiempo-->
            <input type="text" name="lugar" id="lugar" value="" maxlength="120" required>
            <br/>
            <span id="error"></span>
            <input type="submit" id="hoy" name="hoy" value="Previsión Hoy" />
            <input type="submit" id="dias" name="dias" value="Previsión 4 días" />
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <h2>Conectando con la API de tiempo</h2>
    <div class="eltiempo" id="tiempo"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Y a partir de aquí el archivo JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#hoy').click(function() {
  var ubicacion = $('#lugar').val();

  if (ubicacion != '') {

   $.ajax({
    url: "http://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=" + ubicacion + "&units=metric&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     //var infoTiempo = mostrarInfo(data);
     //$('#tiempo').html(infoTiempo);
    }
   });

  } else {
   $('#error').html('El campo ubicación no puede estar vacío');
  }
 });
});

function mostrarInfo(data) {
 return "<h2>El tiempo en</h2><h3>" + data.name + ", " + data.sys.country + "</h3>" +
  "<h2>Tiempo: </h2><h3>" + data.weather[0].main + "</h3>" +
  "<h2>Temperatura: </h2><h3>" + data.main.temp + "</h3>" +
  "<h2>Humedad: </h2><h3>" + data.main.humidity + "</h3>";
}
```

No sé qué es lo que me falla, si alguien me echa una mano. Cuando inspecciono, veo que no me accede a la parte de success de $.ajax

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Aquí dejo enlace porque no sé cómo poner el código bien en la pregunta archivo js https://pastebin.com/StFpvCD0 y archivo HTML https://pastebin.com/vNdgh6zM

Comment: este .js <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script> contiene las funciones javacscript que pusiste tu publicacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve revisando el código y me percate de esto:

```
<input type="submit" id="hoy" name="hoy" value="Previsión Hoy" />
<input type="submit" id="dias" name="dias" value="Previsión 4 días" />
```

Estos botones no pueden ser de tipo submit porque te vuelven a cargar la pagina en vez de lanzarte la peticion ajax. Debe quedarte asi:

```
<input type="button" id="hoy" name="hoy" value="Previsión Hoy" />
    <input type="button" id="dias" name="dias" value="Previsión 4 días" />
```

hecho el cambio en el button y en el javascript funciona correctamente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#hoy').click(function() {
        var ubicacion = $('#lugar').val();

        if (ubicacion != '') {

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=" + ubicacion + '&units=metric&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //console.log(data);
                    var infoTiempo = mostrarInfo(data);

                    $('#tiempo').html(infoTiempo);
                }
            });

        } else {
            $('#error').html('El campo ubicación no puede estar vacío');
        }
    });
});

function mostrarInfo(data) {
    return '<h2> El tiempo en </h2> <h3>' + data.list[0].name +  ', ' + data.list[0].sys.country + '</h3>' + '<h2>Tiempo: </h2><h3>' + data.list[0].weather[0].main + '</h3>' + '<h2>Temperatura: </h2><h3>' + data.list[0].main.temp + '</h3>' + '<h2> Humedad: </h2><h3>' + data.list[0].main.humidity + '</h3>';
}
```

Si deseas mostrar todos los resultado de list recorreo un ciclo y los muestras

Comment: No, laravel no, sólo JavaScript, jquery y ajax

Comment: revisa ahora, lo qeu tenia que ver con laravel era una linea solamente que apra la seguridad de la peticion, pero lo demas es lo mismo para cualquier framework. Revisa el codigo qeu ya pincha bien

Comment: si te sirvio la respuesta, haces una votacion por favot

Comment: Voy a probarlo, gracias.

Comment: y si das un voto perfecto gracias